# Bulk Import Request for FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/bulk-import/blob/master/import.md

I used above link for reference and tried to run import using the following code

```
import requests

url = "https://<fhir-server-name>.azurehealthcareapis.com/$import"

payload = "{\r\n\t\"inputFormat\": \"application/fhir+ndjson\",\r\n\t\"inputSource\": \"https://localhost\",\r\n\t\"storageDetail\": { \"type\": \"https\" },\r\n\t\"input\": [\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t\"type\": \"Patient\",\r\n\t\t\"url\": \"https://localhost/patient_ndjson.ndjson\"\r\n\t}\r\n\t]\r\n}"
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/fhir+json',
  'Prefer': 'respond-async',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <Auth Token>'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

i am receiving 400 Bad Request . i tried posting to both

```
url = "https://<fhir-server-name>.azurehealthcareapis.com/$import"
url = "https://<fhir-server-name>.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient/$import"
```

I used apache for hosting the file and the file is accessible with both http and https.. **Instead of importing it using http server, is there any way to directly point to my local ndjson file** ?

patient_ndjson.ndjson contains

```
{"resourceType":"Patient","id":"8c76dfe7-2b94-497b-9837-8315b150ac0e","meta":{"versionId":"1","lastUpdated":"2020-04-27T11:08:10.611+00:00"},"active":true,"name":[{"use":"official","family":"p000001"}],"gender":"female","birthDate":"2020-04-27T11:00:00+05:30"}
{"resourceType":"Patient","id":"bfab05c7-d36a-4b5a-a0d6-6efb1da0fb3d","meta":{"versionId":"1","lastUpdated":"2020-04-27T11:34:43.83+00:00"},"active":true,"name":[{"use":"official","family":"p000001"}],"gender":"female","birthDate":"2020-04-27T11:00:00+05:30"}
{"resourceType":"Patient","id":"4c314eb1-6309-424b-affc-197fb0131cf6","meta":{"versionId":"1","lastUpdated":"2020-04-27T12:09:20.777+00:00"},"active":true,"name":[{"use":"official","family":"p000002"}],"gender":"female","birthDate":"2020-04-27T03:00:00+05:30"}
```

**Can you please provide some sample request . it would be helpful.**

Comment: Please note that the "$import" operation you linked to at https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/bulk-import/blob/master/import.md is a proposed specification; it's not standardized and not currently supported by production FHIR servers.

Comment: :-( So, in azure fhir api, there is no way to bulk import the data ? with the restriction of 500 max entries in json, i have around 60000 requests and each request is consuming more than 10 to 20 seconds for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$import` is a draft spec and it is not supported (yet) on the Azure API for FHIR.

Comment: Can you suggest any other way of bulk importing the data. As i mentioned, i have hourly data and i have more than 60000 requests

Comment: You have this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483216/sending-bulk-data-to-azure-fhir-server/61491452. That is the answer just send the data in through the API. The $import operation would have to do something similar, it is really just a question of whether you orchestrate it or the server does it for you.

Comment: Fine.. i will try to increase the RU's and post the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484200/inserting-multiple-observation-values-in-single-resource-fhir .  I am not going to do many search operations on the data. if that being the case, is there any way, i can have array of values in observation . Now, for heart- rate of 100 hours, i am creating 100 resources. Instead, if i can have one resource, in which value is represented as array, it would drastically reduce my request count. Can you guide me on how to have observation values as array ?

Comment: You can use sampledata or components in the Observation